# Empty ListView with simple_list_item_multiple_choice layout

Tags: android

How to handle an empty ListView if I use simple_list_item_multiple_choice layout?

'Android Developers' say that I should use the android prefix 
android:id="@android:id/empty
But cannot take in mind how to use it with simple_list_item_multiple_choice

```
protected ListView mFavList; 
ArrayList<String> fakeFavs;

mFavList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,fakeFavs);
```

if fakeFavs is null?

Comment: Try initializing `fakeFavs = new ArrayList<String>()` before setting the adapter.

Comment: Yes, there is initializing string in the code before setting the adapter, but fakeFavs (this is a list of user's contacts) must be set to null at the first run of a program, because the list is empty. I need properly handle the empty list, to show for example a message "No Data".

Comment: use fakeFavs.isEmtpy() then instead of fakeFavs == null

Comment: for example code will be `if (fakeFavs.isEmpty()){
   mFavList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
   android.R.id.empty, fakeFavs));
  }
else {
   mFavList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, fakeFavs));
}`, but where will be "empty" tag?

Comment: where should I write <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
      android:text="No Data"/> if I use simple_list_item_multiple_choice as a layout?

Comment: Do you want to create an item in the listview that says "no data" if the arraylist is null?

Comment: yes, but using standard Android layout. I solved already my problem. Thank you for your responce.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

All I need - "empty" tag in main.xml layout and string of code:
mFavList.setEmptyView(findViewById(android.R.id.empty));

In my program fakeFavs is populating from text file.
In case of empty file, the empty list is properly handled.

Maybe it will be useful for somebody. Working example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class HelloAndroid3 extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

static final String split_symbol = "\n";
protected ListView mFavList;
protected ArrayList<String> fakeFavs;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    fakeFavs = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.mFavList = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.list_favorites);
    refreshFavListItems();
}

private void refreshFavListItems() {

            //put some code here that populates fakeFavs
            //.......
    mFavList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, fakeFavs));
    mFavList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
            mFavList.setEmptyView(findViewById(android.R.id.empty));
            //if fakeFavs will be empty, list shows "No Data" 
}
```

}

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ListView android:id="@+id/list_favorites"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
    />
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:text="No Data"/>
```